# Join three DF - Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing a join with three DF. And I have a problem because when I do the join I got two times the same column.

I have this DF to join with df_c2 and df_c1

```
DF1
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date       | NumToJ   |    Type     |   Sport     |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  31/11/2020 |   1911   |     N2      |  football   | 
|  11/01/2020 |   1891   |     L2      |  tennis     |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

If Type is N2 I join the DF1 with df_c1 where NumToJ have to be equal as Number.

```
df_c1
+---------+-------------+
|  Number | Description |
+---------+-------------+
|  1131   | DATAquality |
|  9103   | DataToRevise|
|  0192   | NoData      |
+---------+-------------+
```

If Type is L2 I join the DF1 with df_c2 where NumToJ have to be equal as Number.

```
df_c2
+---------+-------------+
|  Number | Description |
+-------------+---------+
|  8211   | ReviseAll   |
|  2111   | CancelOperat|
|  9199   | NoData      |
+---------+-------------+
```

And at the end I want to have this:

```
final_df
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date       | NumToJ   |    Type     |   Sport     | Description |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  31/11/2020 |   8211   |     N2      |  football   | ReviseAll   |
|  11/01/2020 |   0192   |     L2      |  tennis     | NoData      |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But I am having this:

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  Date       | NumToJ   |    Type     |   Sport     | Description | Description |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  31/11/2020 |   8211   |     N2      |  football   | ReviseAll   | Null        |
|  11/01/2020 |   0192   |     L2      |  tennis     | Null        | NoData      |
+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I have it in the same column and not in two column the Description?

My code:

```
DF1.join(df_c1, col("Type").equalTo("N2") && col("NumToJ") === df_c1("Number"))
.join(df_c2, col("Type").equalTo("L2") && col("NumToJ") === df_c2("Number"))
```

Comment: `join` twice to create two separate Dataframes and the use `union`?

Comment: maybe do the two joins separeted and then union it? @philantrovert

Comment: How do you get NumToJ as 8211 and 0192 after joining, You don't have these in df?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the dataframe in two and join each with df_cond1 and df_cond2 respectively and union to get all back

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("31/11/2020", "8211", "N2", "football"),
  ("1/01/2020", "0192", "L2", "tennis")
).toDF("Date", "NumToJ", "Type", "Sport")

val df_cond1 = Seq(
  ("1131", "DATAquality"),
  ("9103", "DataToRevise"),
  ("0192", "NoData")
).toDF("Number", "Description")

val df_cond2 = Seq(
  ("8211", "ReviseAll"),
  ("2111", "CancelOperat"),
  ("9199", "NoData")
).toDF("Number", "Description")

val df1 = df.filter($"Type" === "L2")
val df2 = df.except(df1)

df1.join(df_cond1, $"NumToJ" === $"Number")
  .union(df2.join(df_cond2, $"NumToJ" === $"Number"))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+----+--------+------+-----------+
|Date      |NumToJ|Type|Sport   |Number|Description|
+----------+------+----+--------+------+-----------+
|1/01/2020 |0192  |L2  |tennis  |0192  |NoData     |
|31/11/2020|8211  |N2  |football|8211  |ReviseAll  |
+----------+------+----+--------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assemble the all possible matches in one dataset, and then narrow it down by renaming the `Description` column in `df_c1` and `df_c2`, and then creating the new Description column with a conditional:

```
import spark.implicits._
df.join(df_c1.withColumnRenamed("Description", "D1"), 'Number === 'NumToJ, "left")
  .join(df_c2.withColumnRenamed("Description", "D2"), 'Number === 'NumToJ, "left")
  .select('Date,
          'NumToJ,
          'Type,
          'Sport,
          when('Type === "N2", 'D1).when('Type === "L2", 'D2).otherwise(null)
            .as("Description"))
```

Both joins are left-joins, so that columns that don't match df_c1 and df_c2, respectively, are not excluded from the result.